# Elasticsearch query intersection

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-6, elasticsearch-query

We are struggling with a query that we are trying to build, hope you can assist

let’s assume we are indexing cooking recipes , each recipe contains a list of required ingredients.

for example:

```
[
  {
    "name": "omelet",
    "ingredients": {
      "eggs": "2",
      "butter": "1",
      "salt": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "boiled eggs",
    "ingredients": {
      "eggs": "2",
      "salt": "1"
    }
  }
]
```

A customer has in his hands a bunch of ingredients, and wants to know which recipes he can make with them.

```
{
  "ingredients": {
    "eggs": "2",
    "salt": "1",
    "honey": "1"
  }
}
```

How can we express it in an elasticsearch query?  (get all recipes that don’t have ingredients that the customer doesn’t have, In this case return “boiled eggs”)

for clarity :

you can assume that we only need to check if the quantity is equal (no need for greater than/less than, etc...)

note that we cannot index the customer, just the recipes

Comment: Hi. Have you found any solution? We're trying to solve similar task

Comment: not really, except going into scripts territory or checking each and every option (requires to know all the options in advanced)

Answer (score -1):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Link provided is what you are looking for. Bool query will allow you to set greater than parameters and check that all ingredients are available.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how a simple bool query solves this

Comment: Not sure if all bool queries fall under simple. The examples provided in the link solves your problem quite well and has many options.